# Upgrading Postgres database to Postgis 2.1.1

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I executed the postgres 9.1.6 with Postgis 1.5.8 dump from a remote server on Linux

pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -Fc -b -v -f "/somepath/tumidb9.1geom1.5.8.backup" tumidb9

So I have a valid dump

Can I just run the executable postgresql-9.3.0-rc1-linux-x64.run, select the Postgis 2.1.0 option with the check box that specifies prep for restore, create and intialize a new spatial database newdb in the 9.3 instance
and then execute 
perl ../postgis_restore.pl "/somepath/tumidb9.1geom1.5.8.backup" | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres newdb 2> errors.txt on the 9.3 instance.

or do I have to install postgresql-9.1.6-1-linux-x64.run, with the Postgis 2.1.1 option, run the postgis_restore.pl on the 9.1 instance, and then use pg_upgrade to get us to 9.3?

thanks

Comment: Where are you getting "postgresql-9.3.0-rc1-linux-x64.run" from? It's a release candidate. The current version is 9.3.1. What OS are you on?

Comment: The first one, just plopping the dump onto your new 9.3 PgSQL and 2.1.1 PostGIS will work fine.